# How to align word correctly,applying words with and without background color

Tags: html, jquery, css

Now I have to lines with words with and without background color. I would like to align these two lines word by word.

However due to background I set, I can't reach it.

And here's the out come I got for now:

[image]

```css
#b {
  background-color: skyblue;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#g {
  background-color: rgb(109, 221, 109);
  font-family: monospace;
}

#L {
  background-color: red;
  font-family: monospace;
}

mark {
  background-color: yellow;
  /*Add your desired color*/
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<span style="white-space:nowrap">5' UUUUUCUAUUUAGU<span id='L'>|</span>UUUUCU<span id='L'>|</span>G 3'"<br> "3' AAAAA<mark>A</mark>A<mark>C</mark>AAAU<mark id='b'>U</mark>A<span id='L'>|</span>AA<mark id='b'>G</mark><mark id='b'>G</mark>GA<span id='L'>|</span>
<mark id='g'>U</mark> 5'</span>
```

And Here's my expect output:

[expect out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5LQX.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Words? What words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
  <span style="white-space:nowrap">5' UUUUUCUAUUUAGU<span id='L'>|</span>UUUUCU<span id='L'>|</span>G 3'</span>
</div>
<div class="child">
  <span>
    3' AAAAA<span>A</span>A<span>C</span>AAAU<span id='b'>U</span>A<span id='L'>|</span>AA<span id='b'>G</span><span
      id='b'>G</span>GA<span id='L'>|</span><span id='g'>U</span> 5'</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
#b {
     background-color: skyblue;
     /* font-family: monospace; */
 }

#g {
     background-color: rgb(109, 221, 109);
     font-family: monospace;
  }

 #L {
        background-color: red;
        font-family: monospace;
     }

      mark {
        background-color: yellow;
           /*Add your desired color*/
           font-family: monospace;
         }
 .parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
  }
   .child{
      width: auto;
   }
```